# Почему событие onkeypress не реагирует на backspace? И как сделать, чтобы реагировало?

Tags: javascript, html, form

Весь вопрос выше. Допустим, в input вводится число, срабатывает событие onkeypress, которое вызывает функцию. При нажатии backspace - не срабатывает. Я же желаю, чтобы тоже срабатывало ;). Как такое реализовать?

Comment: А вводимое число потом где-то будет использоваться? Потому что можно использовать `oninput`

Comment: Оно срабатывает при нажатии Enter или при выведении из фокуса, не подходит, т.к. используется на динаимческой странице и фокус может остатсья в поле. В любом случае, проблему уже решил и ответил на собственный же вопрос)

Answer (score 0):

Вместо onkeypress сделал событие onkeydown. Всё заработало :)

Comment: Это известная фича. Живой поиск всегда делают по keyup и timeout